# Convert array of float to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have an array of

float `[130101.34764204, 130101.34764606, 130101.34765007]`.

Here, 13 is 2013, 01 is January and 01 is the day. And decimal represents the part of the day, i.e `.34764204*24 = 8.34 (8:34 AM)`. How to convert this to the readable date time format of `2013-01-01 8:34`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Below in a comment you said _It needs to be 2013-01-01 08:20:36.272256 and so on..._ - here you set 8.34 equal to 8:34. What do you finally want? 34% of an hour is 20 minutes, but if you want the first two decimals interpreted as minutes, there should not be more than .59 in the fractional hour part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strptime` and `timedelta` from `datetime` module directly with the integer and the fractional part of the numbers:

```
import datetime as DT

lst = [130101.34764204, 130101.34764606, 130101.34765007]

for l in lst:
    d = int(l)
    t = l - int(l)
    print(DT.datetime.strptime(str(d), '%y%m%d') + DT.timedelta(t))

2013-01-01 08:20:36.272256
2013-01-01 08:20:36.619585
2013-01-01 08:20:36.966048
```

Comment: lol, sorry, I didn't notice that error as I was just looking at the time...  However, this is only a matter of the format string; I just corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this...

```
import datetime


def convert_ts(ts):
    ymd, day_part = divmod(ts, 1)
    y, md = divmod(ymd, 10000)
    m, d = divmod(md, 100)
    day_part_secs = day_part * 86400
    return datetime.datetime(int(2000 + y), int(m), int(d)) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=day_part_secs)
```

Test code:

```
for ts in [
    130101.34764204,
    130101.34764606,
    130101.34765007,
    180702.4,
]:
    print(ts, convert_ts(ts))
```

Output:

```
130101.34764204 2013-01-01 08:20:36.272256
130101.34764606 2013-01-01 08:20:36.619585
130101.34765007 2013-01-01 08:20:36.966048
180702.4 2018-07-02 09:35:59.999999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern to do this For example suppose l is list of floats:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

l = [130101.34764204, 130101.34764606, 130101.34765007]
DAY = 24*60*60

def to_date(f):
    year, month, day, decimal = list(map(int, re.match('(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.(\d+)', "{:.8f}".format(f)).groups(1)))
    seconds = decimal*DAY / 10**8
    return datetime(2000+year, month, day) + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
converted_l = map(to_date, l)
```

Result:

```
for c in converted_l:
    print(c)
2013-01-01 08:20:36.272256
2013-01-01 08:20:36.619584
2013-01-01 08:20:36.966048
```

Comment: May I kindly ask how this can be the accepted answer, while it does not handle the fractional part of the day, loads an additional (quite big) library in opposite to the other answers and processes only one number instead of the whole list?

Comment: still no fractional part of day in spite of needing one more library

Comment: now you patched it (still no seconds though...) but it's much more complicated than the other approaches although you additionally need `re`